# Prove $\sum \sqrt{{\frac {2{a}^{2}b}{a+c}}} \leqq a+b+c$ for $a,b,c>0$

Tags: inequality, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way, cyclic-decomposition

For $a,b,c>0$. Prove that $$\sum \sqrt{{\frac {2{a}^{2}b}{a+c}}} \leqq a+b+c \,\,-----(1)$$

**My solution$:$**

By C-S, we need to prove: $$(\sum ab) \cdot (\sum \frac{2a}{a+c}) \leqq (a+b+c)^2\, (\ast)$$
+) First way to prove $(\ast)$$:$

Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$$,$ it is equivalent to$:$
$$2\,c \left( a-b \right) ^{2} \left( b+a \right) ^{2}+ \left( b-c \right)  \left( a-c \right)  \left\{ {a}^{3}+2\,c{a}^{2}+a{b}^{2}+2\,a bc+{c}^{2}a+{c}^{2}b+b \left( a-b \right) ^{2} \right\} \geqq 0$$
+) And the second$:$ We have:

$$\text{LHS} = (ab+bc+ca)(6 - \sum \frac{2c}{a+c})$$

$$\leqq (ab+bc+ca) \cdot \Big[6- \frac{2(a+b+c)^2}{(ab+bc+ca) +(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\Big]$$

$$=\left( a+b+c \right) ^{2}-{\frac { \left( {a}^{2}-ab-ca+{b}^{2}-bc+{c }^{2} \right)  \left( {a}^{2}+{b}^{2}+{c}^{2} \right) }{{a}^{2}+ab+ca+ {b}^{2}+bc+{c}^{2}}} \leqq (a+b+c)^2$$

PS: Actually the original inequality is$:$

For $a,b,c>0$ and $abc=1$$.$ Prove$:$

$$\sum \sqrt{\frac{ab}{bc^2 +1}} \leqq \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I found $(1)$ when I try to take homogeneous for the original inequality.

What are some other proofs for $(1)$ or the original inequality?

Comment: China TST 2006: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h97495p550608

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG Why, I can't see how to use it for my inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a^2b}{a+c}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(a+c)(b+c)}\sum_{cyc}a(b+c)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(a+c)(b+c)}\sum_{cyc}a(b+c)\leq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2}$$ or
$$(a+b+c)^2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab,$$ which is obviously true by $uvw$, but there is a nice solution by SOS.

Indeed, let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, $$(a+b+c)^2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)-4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b-a^3b^2-a^2b^3+ab^4)-abc\sum_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2ab(a+b-c)\geq(a-c)^2ac(a+c-b)+(b-c)^2bc(b+c-a)\geq$$
$$\geq(b-c)^2ac(a-b)+(b-c)^2bc(b-a)=(b-c)^2(a-b)^2c\geq0.$$

A full expanding we can make by the following way:
$$(a+b+c)^2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)-4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2ab)\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(a^2b+a^2c+\frac{2}{3}abc\right)-4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c+a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^2b^2c+2a^3bc+2a^3b^2+2a^3c^2+4a^3bc+4a^2b^2c+4a^2b^2c)-$$
$$-4\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2+2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c).$$

Comment: There is a very nice SOS for $$(a+b+c)^2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)-4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab\geqq 0$$

Comment: @tthnew I know! But this SOS it's impossible to find during a competition without computer. We don't need to look for this SOS. It's better to make, which I made.

Comment: But what is your idea to get $$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c^2)$$$?$

Comment: This is my SOS: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677527/abc2-prod-cycab-4-sum-cyca2ba2c-sum-cycab-geqq-0

Comment: @tthnew Do you want that I'll show how I made a full expanding? I am ready to show.

Comment: Yeah! Show it please, I realy hope for that!

Comment: @tthnew I added something. See now.

Comment: Wow, nice idea! Thank you!