# Proving $(a+b+c)^2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)-4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab\geqq 0$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

From Mr. Michael Rozenberg [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677190/prove-sum-sqrt-frac-2a2bac-leqq-abc-for-a-b-c0):

For $a,b,c>0$$,$ prove that$:$
$$(a+b+c)^2\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\sum_{cyc}ab,$$
I found two SOS proof:

1) $$\text{LHS-RHS}={\frac { \left( a-b \right) ^{2}\cdot \text{M}+ab \left( {a}^{2
}-2\,ab+ca+{b}^{2}+bc-2\,{c}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{a+b}}$$

Where $$\text{M}=\left( 2\,ab-ca-bc+{c}^{2} \right) ^
{2}+c \left( -c+a+b \right) ^{2} \left( a+b \right)$$

2) $$\text{LHS-RHS}=c \left( a-b \right) ^{2} \left( a+b-c \right) ^{2}+a \left( b-c \right) ^{2} \left( b+c-a \right) ^{2}+b \left( c-a \right) ^{2} \left( c+a-b \right) ^{2}\geqq 0$$

Comment: Yes, of course! But we don't need to look for these forms for the inequality proof.It takes a time, but you want to win.  I think, it's much more better to use the simple SOS. See my solution in the linked topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yeah, you are right, it will take more time if we don't have computer to factor,...

Answer (score 2):

We write the inequality as
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca} \geqslant \frac{\displaystyle 4 \sum (a^2b+ab^2)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)},$$
equivalent to
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca}+2 \geqslant \frac{4[(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-2abc]}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)},$$
or
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca} + \frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \geqslant 2.$$
Which is know.

Comment: Do you find any SOS form for it$?$

Comment: @Nguyenhuyen_AG I did not see it. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think, the shortest way here it's $uvw$. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Indeed, this inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$ and for the proof it's enough to consider two cases:

1. $c=0$;
2. $b=c$, which very easy to make.

Due to the Nguyenhuyen_AG's post your inequality we can rewrite in the following form.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0.$ Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca} + \frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \geqslant 2.$$

There is the following stronger inequality.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $ab+ac+bc\neq0.$ Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{ab+bc+ca} + \frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \geqslant 2+\frac{16(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2}{(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)^4}.$$

Comment: Yeah, but I think it's hard to use for high school student. In Viet Nam, we call high school student is "Học sinh trung học cơ sở". By the way, could you find the stronger for it?

Comment: @tthnew There are infinitely many stronger verses. One of then I posted.